# UIImagePickerController camera keeps open after closing

Tags: ios, swift, swiftui, camera, uiimagepickercontroller

I wrote a `UIViewControllerRepresentable` for a `VideoRecordingView` in SwiftUI:

```
import SwiftUI
import AVFoundation
import Photos

struct VideoRecordingView: UIViewControllerRepresentable {

@Binding var videoURL: URL?
@Environment(\.viewController) private var viewControllerHolder: UIViewController?
let imagePickerController: UIImagePickerController

init(videoURL: Binding<URL?>) {
    self._videoURL = videoURL
    imagePickerController = UIImagePickerController()
}

func makeUIViewController(context: UIViewControllerRepresentableContext<VideoRecordingView>) -> UIImagePickerController {
    
    imagePickerController.allowsEditing = true
    imagePickerController.sourceType = .camera
    imagePickerController.mediaTypes = ["public.movie"]
    imagePickerController.videoMaximumDuration = .infinity
    if #available(iOS 14.0, *) {
        imagePickerController.videoQuality = .typeHigh
    } else {
    }
    imagePickerController.delegate = context.coordinator
    
    return imagePickerController
}

func updateUIViewController(_ uiViewController: UIImagePickerController, context: UIViewControllerRepresentableContext<VideoRecordingView>) {}

func makeCoordinator() -> Coordinator {
    Coordinator(self)
}

final class Coordinator: NSObject, UIImagePickerControllerDelegate, UINavigationControllerDelegate {
    
    var parent: VideoRecordingView
    
    init(_ parent: VideoRecordingView) {
        self.parent = parent
        NotificationCenter.default.addObserver(forName: UIApplication.willResignActiveNotification, object: nil, queue: nil) { notification in
            parent.imagePickerController.stopVideoCapture()
            //                parent.viewControllerHolder?.dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)
            
        }
    }
    
    func requestAuthorizationToPhotos(completionHandler: @escaping (Bool) -> Void) {
        guard PHPhotoLibrary.authorizationStatus() != .authorized else {
            completionHandler(true)
            return
        }
        PHPhotoLibrary.requestAuthorization { status in
            completionHandler(status == .authorized ? true : false)
        }
    }
    
    func imagePickerControllerDidCancel(_ picker: UIImagePickerController) {
        picker.stopVideoCapture()
        parent.viewControllerHolder?.dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)
    }
    
    func imagePickerController(_ picker: UIImagePickerController, didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo info: [UIImagePickerController.InfoKey : Any]) {
        
        picker.stopVideoCapture()
        
        if let videoURL = info[UIImagePickerController.InfoKey.mediaURL] as? URL {
            
            DispatchQueue.global(qos: .background).async {
                let fileURL = videoURL.copyFileToTempDirectory()
                DispatchQueue.main.async {
                    self.parent.videoURL = fileURL
                }
                
                self.requestAuthorizationToPhotos { granted in
                    if (granted && UIVideoAtPathIsCompatibleWithSavedPhotosAlbum(videoURL.path)) {
                        UISaveVideoAtPathToSavedPhotosAlbum(videoURL.path, nil, nil, nil)
                    }
                }
            }
            
        }
        parent.viewControllerHolder?.dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)
    }
    
}
```

}

I use `imagePickerController.stopVideoCapture()` and dismiss it, when I close it.

When I close it, I exit the app and go back to the app again. (I go to the background and return to the foreground.)

At this time, a green light appears in the status bar, which means it is using the camera. While it is closed and I do not know which part of my code is using the camera.

Please help me. Thanks :)

Comment: Is `imagePickerController` a property on a class? Are you setting it to `nil` when you're done with it?

Comment: Where is SwiftUI here?

Comment: Welcome to SO - Please take the [tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour) and read [How to Ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) to improve, edit and format your questions. 

Without a [Minimal Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) it is impossible to help you troubleshoot.

Comment: @shim thanks but it doesn't work

Comment: @swiftPunk i put all of code in the question, thanks

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.